# Google Sheets - Multipling a cell(weight) by another(rate) based on its value compared to a column of cells

Tags: google-sheets, compare, formula

I want to compare the value of cell(**K5**) against column **A** to determine the range its rate will fall under.  Once the proper rate is determined, I want to multiply that row with its values on column **B**, **C**, etc and output it on cells (**L5**, **M5**, etc)

for example if the CW(**K5**) is **755.5** then its range falls under cell **A8**(**500+**) so we can multiply CW(**K5**) by **B8** and **C8** and output the product on **L5**, **M5** respectively.

Eventually I will have many more rows so is probably a better idea to have rates(columns A, B, C) in a separate sheet, is that even possible?

the actual sheet
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've made similar data sheet, but removed strings with actual numbers to look for in column `A`. And then used `vlookup` for sorted range `A:C`:

[image]

The formula for `F2` is:

`=VLOOKUP(E2,$A:$C,2)`

The formula for `G2` is:

`=VLOOKUP(E2,$A:$C,3)`

This technique may help you.